# Worksheet_change working, but won't call a sub routine

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2021

I've been searching for an answer but nothing fits my problem.  I have Sheet 1 where I've created a private sub ("disable1") to enable or disable a checkbox based on the value of a cell.  I then created a Worksheet_Change in Sheet 1 ("Entry Sheet") to call disable1.  I've done this same thing on another workbook and it works fine.  If I go into disable1 and click F5, it works like a charm.  With it in Worksheet_Change, it does nothing. I checked and Application.EnableEvents is True in the Immediate window.  I know I'm in the right worksheet.  The macro works when manually forced.  I added a msgbox to the Worksheet_Change to confirm it is indeed working.  I put the box before the Call disable1 and then after the Call disable1 line.  It worked both times.  I am at a loss here.  What am I doing wrong? (I use the call function in Worksheet_Change to keep activities separated for me to keep track of.)

```
Private Sub disable1()

    If Sheets("Entry Sheet").Range("J15").Value = "Site Area Emergency" Then
        CheckBox1.Enabled = True
    ElseIf Sheets("Entry Sheet").Range("J15").Value = "General Emergency" Then
        CheckBox1.Enabled = True
    ElseIf Sheets("Entry Sheet").Range("J15").Value = "Alert" Then
        CheckBox1.Enabled = False
    ElseIf Sheets("Entry Sheet").Range("J15").Value = "" Then
        CheckBox1.Enabled = False

    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)


    Call disable1
    MsgBox "changed:" & Target.Address
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Btw, if `disable1` is in the sheet code module, you can use `Me` in place of `Sheets("Entry Sheet")` to refer to the parent sheet.

Comment: Have you tried stepping `(F8)` through the code to see what is happening?

Comment: ... or adding a `Debug.Print` or `MsgBox` to `disable1` to verify that it's actually being called?

Comment: Add a breakpoint at the `Call disable1` line by clicking on the left margin there. Then make any change to the worksheet that would trigger the event. Press F8 to step through the code line-by-line in debug mode. Please pay attention to check the value in cell J15 - if it is NOT one of the four values checked in the `disable1` subroutine, you'll notice Checkbox1 does not get modified, which explains the unexpected behavior.

Comment: I've tested the code and it works for me. The checkbox gets grayed out (`.Enabled = False)` when J15 is empty or having "Alert" and gets enabled again with "General Emergency" for example. Have you changed the name of the checkbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the way I'd set up the radio buttons was not making the worksheet see a change was happening.  When I changed from linking the properties to a cell to a macro, everything worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

### A Worksheet Change: Toggle CheckBox

[image]

**Sheet Module, e.g. `Sheet1`**

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Dim cell As Range: Set cell = Me.Range("J15")
    If Intersect(cell, Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    ToggleCheckBox cell, Me.CheckBox1
    
End Sub
```

**Standard Module, e.g. `Module1`**

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ToggleCheckBox( _
        ByVal cell As Range, _
        ByVal cbx As Object)

    Dim CellString As String: CellString = CStr(cell.Value)
    
    Select Case CellString
        Case "Site Area Emergency", "General Emergency"
            cbx.Enabled = True
        Case "Alert", ""
            cbx.Enabled = False
        Case Else
            MsgBox "Invalid string """ & CellString & """.", vbCritical
    End Select

End Sub
```

- By putting the `ToggleCheckBox` procedure in a standard module, you can easily (without specifying the module) utilize it with another worksheet, e.g. `Sheet2`:

**Sheet Module, e.g. `Sheet2`**

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Dim cell As Range: Set cell = Me.Range("A1") ' ***
    If Intersect(cell, Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    ToggleCheckBox cell, Me.CheckBox2 ' ***
    
End Sub
```